# Cómo podría traer los datos de este JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Este es el JSON, pero no sé cómo poner correctamente los `JSONArray` y `JSONObject` para llegar hasta el atributo `name` en lenguaje de JAVA:

```
{
    "RestResponse": {
        "messages": [
            "Total [249] records found."
        ],
        "result": [{
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "alpha2_code": "AF",
            "alpha3_code": "AFG"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Mandy, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). A esta pregunta le hace falta algo de información: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estás usando? ¿qué investigación has realizado? ¿qué has intentado y cómo falló? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Mandy bienvenida al sitio, agrega lo que has tratado como comenta Alvaro y obtendrás muy buenas respuestas!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podes usar lo siguiente

```
Object obj;

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("result");
```

despues iteramos el array y conseguimos cada objeto adentro de result

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    String name   = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    String alpha2 = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("alpha2_code");
    String alpha3 = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("alpha3_code");
}
```

Tambien lo podes hacer mas facil sin hacer un loop, el loop lo hacemos por si tenes varios resultados en vez de uno

```
String name   = array.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
```

Esto te define un objeto

```
  "result": {
        ....
        }
```

y esto un array

```
"result": [{
            ....
            }]
```

Si tienes alguna duda sobre esto consultalo en los comentarios

Comment: Esta bien tu respuesta, solo que en el JSONArray se debe ocupar el objeto jsonObject y no obj

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: No entiendo por que mi respuesta estaria fuera de lugar a una pregunta que solicita lo que respondi, y no entiendo tampoco por que alguien pondria -1 si es la respuesta a lo que OP pregunta, realmente aveces no dan muchas ganas de contribuir asi :/

Comment: @GastónSaillén no tomes tanta importancia a los puntos virtuales de SO, si tu respuesta es buena otros usuarios lo apreciaran y te daran el upvote.

Comment: no le tomo mucha importancia, lo que pasa es que para mi es como que downvote significa que lo que respondiste esta mal, y no le veo lo mal por eso me parece raro, la idea es que ayude al que pregunta y con downvote pareceria que el que lee piense que esta mal

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió de ayuda tu respuesta Gastón Saillén

Comment: un gusto que te haya servido mandy, cualquier duda me consultas, un saludo